# Conduit - Splitting a ByteString source to chunks of bytes

Tags: haskell, conduit

With `sourceFile` we get a ByteString stream.

With reference to my other question ["Combining multiple Sources/Producers into one"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321983/conduit-combining-multiple-sources-producers-into-one/23325248?noredirect=1#comment35756738_23325248), I'm able to get a source of (StdGen, ByteString) using `ZipSink`, `sourceFile` and a custom source that produces an infinite stream of StdGen.

What I'm trying to achieve is to pair each StdGen with one single byte of ByteString, but with my current implementation, I'm getting one StdGen paired with the whole content of the input file from `sourceFile`.

I have looked into `Conduit.Binary`'s `isolate` function, but it doesn't seem to be working for me when I use as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import System.Random (StdGen(..), split, newStdGen, randomR)
import ClassyPrelude.Conduit as Prelude
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT, ResourceT(..))
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Conduit.Binary (isolate)

-- generate a infinite source of random number seeds
sourceStdGen :: MonadIO m => Source m StdGen
sourceStdGen = do
    g <- liftIO newStdGen
    loop g
    where loop gin = do
            let g' = fst (split gin)
            yield gin
            loop g'

-- combine the sources into one
sourceInput :: (MonadResource m, MonadIO m) => FilePath -> Source m (StdGen, ByteString)
sourceInput fp = getZipSource $ (,)
    <$> ZipSource sourceStdGen
    <*> ZipSource (sourceFile fp $= isolate 1)

-- a simple conduit, which generates a random number from provide StdGen
-- and append the byte value to the provided ByteString
simpleConduit :: Conduit (StdGen, ByteString) (ResourceT IO) ByteString
simpleConduit = mapC process 

process :: (StdGen, ByteString) -> ByteString
process (g, bs) =
    let rnd = fst $ randomR (40,50) g
    in bs ++ pack [rnd]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    runResourceT $ sourceInput "test.txt" $$ simpleConduit =$ sinkFile "output.txt"
```

In Conduit terms, I thought `isolate` will do an `await`, yield the `head` of the incoming ByteString stream, and `leftOver` the rest (put it back to the incoming stream's queue). Basically, what I'm trying to do is chopping the incoming ByteString stream into blocks of bytes.

Am I using it correctly? If `isolate` is not the function I should be using, then can anyone provide another function that splits it into arbitrary byte chunks?

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. You're saying that you want a separate `StdGen` per `Word8`? In other words, you want a stream of `(StdGen, Word8)`?

Comment: @Michael, that's right.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman, Would you be able to check the conduit I've written? (`condWord`). Did I just reinvented the wheel since I'd expect `Conduit.Binary` library having something similar (and probably more versatile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write a conduit myself (`condWord`) which splits incoming ByteString into Word8 chunks. I'm not sure whether I'm reinventing the wheel here though.

To get my intended behavior, I simply bolt `condWord` onto `sourceFile`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import System.Random (StdGen(..), split, newStdGen, randomR)
import ClassyPrelude.Conduit as Prelude
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT, ResourceT(..))
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Conduit.Binary (isolate)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

-- generate a infinite source of random number seeds
sourceStdGen :: MonadIO m => Source m StdGen
sourceStdGen = do
    g <- liftIO newStdGen
    loop g
    where loop gin = do
            let g' = fst (split gin)
            yield gin
            loop g'

-- combine the sources into one
sourceInput :: (MonadResource m, MonadIO m) => FilePath -> Source m (StdGen, Word8)
sourceInput fp = getZipSource $ (,)
    <$> ZipSource sourceStdGen
    <*> ZipSource (sourceFile fp $= condWord)

-- a simple conduit, which generates a random number from provide StdGen
-- and append the byte value to the provided ByteString
simpleConduit :: Conduit (StdGen, Word8) (ResourceT IO) ByteString
simpleConduit = mapC process 

process :: (StdGen, Word8) -> ByteString
process (g, ch) =
    let rnd = fst $ randomR (97,122) g
    in pack [fromIntegral ch, rnd]

condWord :: (Monad m) => Conduit ByteString m Word8
condWord = do
    bs <- await
    case bs of
        Just bs' -> do
            if (null bs')
                then return ()
                else do
                    let (h, t) = fromJust $ BS.uncons bs'
                    yield h
                    leftover t 
                    condWord
        _ -> return ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
    runResourceT $ sourceInput "test.txt" $$ simpleConduit =$ sinkFile "output.txt"
```

Comment: [concatC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-combinators-0.2.5/docs/Conduit.html#v:concatC) will actually do the same thing as `condWord`. A simply approach would also be `awaitForever $ mapM_ yield . BS.unpack`.

Comment: Lovely, and there's a bunch of them at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-combinators!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
import System.Random (StdGen, split, newStdGen, randomR)
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Conduit 
import Data.ByteString (ByteString, pack, unpack, singleton)
import Control.Monad.Trans (MonadIO (..))
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as L
import Data.Monoid ((<>))

input :: MonadIO m => FilePath -> Source m (StdGen, ByteString)
input path = do 
  gs <- unfoldr (Just . split) `fmap` liftIO newStdGen 
  bs <- (map singleton . unpack) `fmap` liftIO (BS.readFile path)
  mapM_ yield (zip gs bs)

output :: Monad m => Sink (StdGen, ByteString) m ByteString
output = L.foldMap (\(g, bs) -> let rnd = fst $ randomR (97,122) g in bs <> pack [rnd])

main :: IO ()
main = (input "in.txt" $$ output) >>=  BS.writeFile "out.txt"
```

It is probably more efficient to omit `map singleton`, you may as well use the `Word8`s directly and convert back to `ByteString` at the end.

Comment: I noticed that you're not using `sinkFile`. Doesn't this mean that you're not really streaming to your output file, but instead storing it all in memory first and then writing to output using `BS.writeFile`?